# how to store a user input into a variable whith the type of char *?

Tags: pointers, char

Here is my code
and it doesn't work. I think the problem is in the scanf line. If you can help me guys

```
char * name;
name = "random name";
puts(name);

printf("Enter a name: ");
scanf("%s", name);
puts(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1**

You need to allocate some memory first using **malloc**, and then free the memory, your pointer when it is declared has a garbage value.

```
char * name;
printf("Enter a name: ");

name = malloc (sizeof (char) * 81);
fgets (name, 80, stdin);

puts(name);
free(name);
```

source: ([Taking input string from keyboard in C using pointer notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28423752/taking-input-string-from-keyboard-in-c-using-pointer-notation))

**Answer 2**

I would recommend using a fixed char array value. It's clean, safer, and doesn't need to make memory management.

```
char name[20];

printf("Enter a name: ");
scanf("%s", name);
puts(name);
```